# While loop excluding multiples of specific number

Tags: c++

I'm working on c++ and I need help writing a program that prints all numbers between 1 and 200 excluding multiples of 7. I understand how to print the number between 1 and 200, but I don't understand how to print them excluding multiples of 7.

Comment: Too many possible options.   No effort shown other than posting the question.   Voted to close accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Use the modulo operator `%` to determine if the number is a multiple of 7.

if `number % 7 == 0`, then it's a multiple of seven, and then you don't print it.

Answer (score -1):

You can pre calculate the multiples of 7, storing them somewhere.
Then, for every value in the 'for' you print only if the number is not in where you stored the pre calculations.